# General formula for the definite integral of form $\int \frac{dx}{\tan(ax)^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals

I am not entirely sure where I went wrong with my approach so I wanted to share it with you guys, thanks for any insights or for spotting some silly mistake.

$$\int \frac{dx}{\tan(ax)^n}$$

First, I made a substitution as such:  $u = \tan(ax)$ thus obtaining $$a\sec(ax)^2dx = du$$ rewriting it gives us $$a(\tan(ax)^2+1)dx = du$$

Then I rewrote the integral with the substitution as follows:

$$\frac{1}{a}\int \frac{du}{u^n(u^2 + 1)}$$

Then I integrate as follows  (following step is wrong, this should be done with partial decomposition but is it possible?):

$$\frac{1}{a}\int \frac{du}{u^n(u^2 + 1)} = \frac{1}{a}\ln \left| u^{n+2} + u^n \right| \cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)u^{n+1} + (n-1)u^{n-1}} + C$$

Then substituting back results in:

$$\frac{1}{a}\ln \left| u^{n+2} + u^n \right| \cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)u^{n+1}} + (n-1)u^{n-1} + C = \frac{1}{a}\ln \left| \tan(ax)^{n+2} + \tan(ax)^n \right| \cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)\tan(ax)^{n+1} + (n-1)\tan(ax)^{n-1}} + C$$

Testing my answer with $\cot(3x)^4$ I get a very similar graph to the answer in the book but it is slightly off I can't seem to find the mistake. Thanks for any insights.

It seems that my mistake is the integration step as I do not get a log integral, it is wrong. I should consider partial decomposition, but then is it possible to generalise it?

$\textbf{Update:}$ so far I have only realised that if we play around with different powers $n$ we notice that if there is a general expression, it is different for odd and even powers; I conjecture that we indeed can find it, but two separate expressions.

Comment: How did you get $$\frac{1}{a}\int \frac{du}{u^n(u^2 + 1)} = \frac{1}{a}\ln \left| u^{n+2} + u^n \right| \cdot \frac{1}{(n+1)u^{n+1} + (n-1)u^{n-1}} + C$$?

Comment: yes. This is my mistake, now I am thinking how to fix it, I cannot just take the log... You are right

Comment: I have edited the last bit of the question as it is indeed wrong

Comment: Mathematica shows the result is $\frac{\tan ^{1-n}(a x) \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{2};\frac{3}{2}-\frac{n}{2};-\tan ^2(a x)\right)}{a-a n}$   , where $_2F_1$ is `Hypergeometric2F1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I_n=\int \frac{du}{u^n(u^2 + 1)}$$

If you use Mathematica, it returns, as @138Aspen wrote in comments
$$I_n=\frac{u^{1-n} }{1-n}\,
   _2F_1\left(1,\frac{1-n}{2};\frac{3-n}{2};-u^2\right)$$ or
$$I_n=-\frac{1}{2}  i^{n+1}\, B_{-u^2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{2},0\right)$$

The problem is that, if $n$ is odd, Mathematica returns the unpleasant `ComplexInfinity`.

I think that it would be better to analyze the structure of the individual integrals
$$\large\color{blue}{I_{2n}=(-1)^n \tan^{-1}(u)+P_n(u)}$$ where
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n \\
 1 & -\frac{1}{u} \\
 2 & -\frac{1}{3 u^3}+\frac{1}{u} \\
 3 & -\frac{1}{5 u^5}+\frac{1}{3 u^3}-\frac{1}{u} \\
 4 & -\frac{1}{7 u^7}+\frac{1}{5 u^5}-\frac{1}{3 u^3}+\frac{1}{u}
   \\
 5 & -\frac{1}{9 u^9}+\frac{1}{7 u^7}-\frac{1}{5 u^5}+\frac{1}{3
   u^3}-\frac{1}{u} \\
 6 & -\frac{1}{11 u^{11}}+\frac{1}{9 u^9}-\frac{1}{7
   u^7}+\frac{1}{5 u^5}-\frac{1}{3 u^3}+\frac{1}{u} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\large\color{blue}{I_{2n+1}=(-1)^n \frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{u^2+1}{u^2}\right)+Q_n(u)}$$ where
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & Q_n \\
 1 & -\frac{1}{2 u^2} \\
 2 & -\frac{1}{4 u^4}+\frac{1}{2 u^2} \\
 3 & -\frac{1}{6 u^6}+\frac{1}{4 u^4}-\frac{1}{2 u^2} \\
 4 & -\frac{1}{8 u^8}+\frac{1}{6 u^6}-\frac{1}{4 u^4}+\frac{1}{2
   u^2} \\
 5 & -\frac{1}{10 u^{10}}+\frac{1}{8 u^8}-\frac{1}{6
   u^6}+\frac{1}{4 u^4}-\frac{1}{2 u^2} \\
 6 & -\frac{1}{12 u^{12}}+\frac{1}{10 u^{10}}-\frac{1}{8
   u^8}+\frac{1}{6 u^6}-\frac{1}{4 u^4}+\frac{1}{2 u^2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The patterns are quite obvious.

Comment: I just substituted $u=1/y$ and got $\int \frac{y^n}{1+y^2} \, \mathrm{d}y$. Now this can be done easily with geometric series. I got $\int \frac{1}{(\tan{a x})^n} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{n+2k+1} \left( \frac{1}{\tan{ax}} \right)^{n+2k+1} + \mathrm{C}$ Can we proceed like this??

Comment: @LuckyChouhan. This is very correct. I did not want (on purpose) to go beyond what was written in the post. But make an answer with it. By the way, I think that $(-1)^{k+1}$. The problem is that, as with the hypergeometric function, you have an infinite sum. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I can see we arrived at the same pattern conclusion for both cases but unfortunately, I haven't learnt about hypergeometric functions yet, so I am not sure what is going on with the generalised parts, looking forward to learning about it. Thanks!

Comment: @LuckyChouhan Could you explain why we can do it geometric series? I don't really understand

Comment: @TeodorasPaura. Forget the hypergeometric function and the infinite sums. The patterns are quite simple for $P_n$ and $Q_n$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici okay, Thank you! I was too scared to post my answer haha :)

Comment: @TeodorasPaura I wrote $\frac{1}{1+y^2} = 1-y^2+y^4-\cdots$ Then integrated term by term. So sorry for late reply, actually I just opened MSE and saw.

Comment: @LuckyChouhan ohh I see, thank you!! no worries :)